# Validate "path"

Tags: powershell, path

The following code works to run powercfg.exe, but I would like to make it more flexible and user friendly by testing for powercfg.exe and exiting gracefully with a logged error when the user provides a bad $executable. It seems that the file is being found in some part of %path%, but Test-Path is not resolving the path the same way Start-Process does. Is there some mechanism to expand the path automatically, or do i need to actually use the Path env var to do this manually?

```
$resource = 'C:\rtc.pow'
$executable = "powercfg.exe"
$argumentList = "-import $resource d03b6c96-607f-412c-b47b-417fa8d391af"
Start-Process -FilePath:$executable -argumentList:$argumentList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get-command powercfg.exe` and get its `Path` attribute to receive full name of the executable.

```
PS C:\Users\me> get-command powercfg.exe | select -expand path
C:\Windows\system32\powercfg.exe
```

Comment: Oh, now there's one of those little PS tricks I like. Now to put a nice try/catch around it and I'm off to the races. Thanks!